# How to make adb to listen on all interfaces?

Tags: android, networking, adb

I'm trying to get adb to listen to all interfaces on a machine so I can access it from another machine (via adb -H).

However, when I start adb with -a it still only listens on localhost.

eg.

```
aclark@corydoras 0 ~ $ adb -a start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now at tcp:5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
aclark@corydoras 0 ~ $ netstat -anp | grep 5037
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5037          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31587/adb
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:50408         127.0.0.1:5037          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5037          127.0.0.1:42885         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5037          127.0.0.1:49051         TIME_WAIT   -
aclark@corydoras 0 ~ $
```

I was expecting to see the service listening on 0.0.0.0:5037, not 127.0.0.1:5037.

How do I get adb to listen on all interfaces?

edit:

On the server machine, start `adb` with:

`adb -a nodaemon server`

On the client machine:

`adb -H [IP] [command]`

Comment: The linked answer contains a working `adb server` command which actually makes it listen on `0.0.0.0:5037`

Comment: So it does, I must have missed that when I scanned through last night @alex-p. Any chance you can change the formatting of that answer so the vital commands are all on lines by themselves and stand out more?