# adb port forwarding to listen on all interfaces

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to redirect/forward a TCP port from the local machine to the device (where I have a server listening on a given port). The command I'm using is the following:

```
adb forward -a tcp:5555 tcp:5555
```

However, when I check with netstat I see that adb is only listening on 127.0.0.1. I need adb to listen on any IP not only the local host. Is this possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44963981/1778421

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After a while looking around this issue I finally found the solution. It seems that for whatever reason adb is not processing the "-a" option (for me it seems like a bug in adb .. but I'm not sure). The alternative, is to start the daemon server and pass this option to it as following:

```
adb -a nodaemon server start
```

Once we start the server then the tcp forward now is listening in all the interfaces instead of localhost.

**[EDIT]**

Some times you may get an error like:

```
>  could not install smartsocket listener: Address already
```

This is because there's already an adb server running so you have to kill it (`adb kill-server`) before starting the new one.

Comment: i get this error ./adb -a nodaemon server start
adb F 05-16 05:37:57 11250 11250 main.cpp:153] could not install *smartsocket* listener: Address already in use
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: This happens when you have another adb server already running. you have to kill the running adb before launching yours.

Comment: This is hidden and weird, but **effective**!!

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot. I just want to add one more thing. To stop the currently running adb process you have to exit IntelliJ/Android-Studio. If you’re trying to “kill” the running adb process manually while IntelliJ/Android-Studio is still running it will keep restarting the adb process!

Comment: this is an excellent find and impossible to find within the official adb docs

Answer (score 0):

Found that with version 1.0.41 of adb tool you can now do
`adb -a tcpip 5037`
to get the same result.  Maybe the -a "bug" is fixed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35749067)